# How to clean pomegranate drops from the ocher waterproof wall paint?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen, paint

I have some **ocher** (ochre) **walls** painted with a **waterproof paint** (this is how it's called, but it seems like not so resistant to water). I cut a **pomegranate** and some drops fell on the wall.

The ocher nuance looks almost like a (255, 220, 180) RGB color:
[image: ochre wall]
and the drops created light gray spots.

I tried to blur the spots by dabbing and rubbing with a wet sponge, but the spots are too deep. Also, the ochre has tinted orange near the grey spots.

How can I remove/cover them to be less emphasized?

Answer (score 2):

If you try to blur it using the wet sponge, there is a chance to make the situation worse. So I suggest you to the following steps:

- If the spots are at the center of a wall or at a position where eye gets contact instantly due to off color, then you try hiding it with any curious available. This arrangement can be done until you paint your wall for the next time.
- For testing purpose, the small quantity of paint is available with requested color. You can request for your color, have it painted on the spots. This would be the best idea as having this color in stock will help you if the same problem occurs in near future too as your painted surface is more prone to similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to fix a problem like this brings the liklihood of making it worse. Most fruit stains are not lightfast,famously red wine, and lose their brilliance and fade to to neutral in a year or two.Unless your problem is driving you up the wall, lol, the easiest course might be the best one

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You aren't quite clear: is "the easiest course" leaving it alone?